# Invoke only by a single thread

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

I wrote a simple class in Python, which controls code invocation, in a multi-threaded environment, with the following logic:

The class' main method, named `try_to_do`, takes two function pointers as arguments: `yes_we_can_fn` and `no_we_cannot_fn`.

In any point in time, only a single thread can invoke code the function passed as `yes_we_can_fn` argument.

If a specific thread tries to invoke its code, but some other thread is already invoking its code, then the `no_we_cannot_fn` is invoked **instead of** `yes_we_can_fn`.

If there's an exception in the code being executed, it should raise to the calling context.

The code:

```
from threading import Lock

class MyController():
    def __init__(self):
        self.locker = Lock()
        self.is_active = False

    def try_to_do(self, yes_we_can_fn, no_we_cannot_fn):
        with self.locker:
            if self.is_active:
                we_can_do_it = False
            else:
                we_can_do_it = True
                self.is_active = True

        try:
            if we_can_do_it:
                yes_we_can_fn()
            else:
                no_we_cannot_fn()
        finally:
            if we_can_do_it:
                with self.locker:
                    self.is_active = False
```

Usage:

```
ctl = MyController()

def p1():
    from time import sleep
    print 'before sleep'
    sleep(2)
    print 'done'

def p2():
    print 'too busy, will try some other time'

ctl.try_to_do(p1, p2)
```

I'd like to get some reviews: thread safety (maybe I'm missing something?), coding style, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid the `is_active` variable by using the lock in a non-blocking manner:

```
def try_to_do(self, yes_we_can_fn, no_we_cannot_fn):
    if self.locker.acquire(False):
        try:
            yes_we_can_fn()
        finally:
            self.locker.release()
    else:
        no_we_cannot_fn()
```

Comment: That's a great idea. Note that there should also be a `try/finally` around the `no_we_cannot_fn()`.

Comment: @RonKlein In your version the `finally` block does nothing in the case where `no_we_cannot_fn()` gets called.

Comment: After another look in your suggested code, I see that even if there was as exception while invoking `no_we_cannot_fn`, the class' state won't get affected. In my (original) code, it would be. So you're absolutely right, there's no need for a `try` wrapper around `no_we_cannot_fn()` in your suggestion.